# How can i send api requests and get the answers using boto3?

Tags: boto3, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have my bot already built on Lex.

I'm trying to interact with it on python, to send a request (sentence) and parse the answer.

For that purpose, I spent some time now reading and rereading these docs: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lex-runtime.html#LexRuntimeService.Client.generate_presigned_url

But I can't seem to understand how to send these requests and which function will actually give me the answer from the bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try [post_text()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lex-runtime.html#LexRuntimeService.Client.post_text) method?

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('lex-runtime')
response = client.post_text(
    botName='string',
    botAlias='string',
    userId='string',
    sessionAttributes={
        'string': 'string'
    },
    requestAttributes={
        'string': 'string'
    },
    inputText='string'
)
```

this function will give you the answer from the bot and it will be stored in `response` variable.
write the code in Lambda function and give permission to access Lex.

hope it helps.

Comment: you need to fill the values in place of 'string'