# How can I integrate my Lex chatbot with my website , actually I want to set up Lambda function and create an API gateway to post and get responses

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-lex

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    responderName = event["DestinationBot"]
    userId = event["SenderID"]
    userInput = event["message"]["text"]

    client = boto3.client('lex-runtime')

    response = client.post_text(
        botName=responderName,
        botAlias="iSearchBotBeta",
        userId=userId,
        sessionAttributes={
        },
        requestAttributes={
        },
        inputText= userInput
    )
```

Actually I already have created an chatbot in lex environment .But the problem is I want to integrate my lex chatbot response with my website using http post and get .Actually I am not getting any good solution.I would be happy if it could be provided in python because my lambdahook and fulfillment lambda's of lex all are written in python.

I have tried to call via a post request from another lambda but its not working correctly,actually I think, i am following wrong process.I would be helpful greatly if I get any solution.

I expect that it is possible but how ? .I am not getting any example of such .A small example of using lex api would be helpful to post and get things from a lambda would be great

Comment: @sid8491 please help

Comment: Let's see the code you are using to post via the Lex API. Are you using [PostText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) to send to your Lex bot?

Comment: .Thanks for helping me out.No,I have just made the lambdahook for fulfillment and DialogCodeHook actually I need a way to be able to post text and get response from lex via a lambda in json.Please give me example of lambda

Comment: The code I have written isnt of any use i think !

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47948969/399435) for an example.